# How to find location of JTree node on screen

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jtree, swingutilities

I want to search a particular node of JTree and determine its location on screen. My aim is to start hovering mouse from the top left corner of that node and perform a mouse click in my JFC.

Can anyone help me with this? Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by finding a node on screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knowing the coordinates x and y (from the mouse event), you can get the path via `JTree.getPathForLocation`. The bounds of the node are returned by `JTree.getPathBounds(path)`.

Comment: This gives the location of x and y of origin. How to get the location of rightmost x and y?

Comment: @DarkKnight `getPathBounds` returns a `Rectangle`. The right most x position is `bounds.x + bounds.width` and the right most y position is `bounds.x + bounds.height`

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more information, it's hard to nail this down.

However, I'd suggest you take a look at

- [JTree.getPathBounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getPathBounds%28javax.swing.tree.TreePath%29)
- [JTree.getRowBounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getRowBounds%28int%29)
- [JTree.getRowForPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getRowForPath%28javax.swing.tree.TreePath%29)
- [SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPointToScreen%28java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.Component%29)

This should help you work out where on the screen a node is

Answer (score 1):

You can use processMouseEvent. And the MouseEvent will get you the X and Y coordinates of your mouse.